# WSO2 ESB REST API Port Change

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Do we have a feature in WSO2 ESB REST API where we can deploy REST API services on Carbon server with different ports.

In the sense, REST-API-1 with port 1000
REST-API-2 with port 2000 and so on.

I don't want to use server port which is by default 8280 for all REST services.
I need unique ports for each REST API Service as mentioned above.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: What you describe seems quite odd. Can you explain the reasoning for wanting seperate port numbers for each api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. What you ca do is change the port. But you can't use different ports for each service.